# Why Is This Searching Algorithm Bizarrely not Working for this Case?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am somewhat new to Java, and I was learning the concept of recursion. I was creating a recursive algorithm that checks if an element exists in a Comparable array by using the compareTo method. Although the algorithm works in most cases, for some reason it does not seem to find an element in the second half. For example, if the array is {3, 5, 1, 9, 11}, calling the method on 3, 5, 1 successfully returns true, but calling the method on 9, 11 returns false. Attached is the code, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
  @SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
  public boolean searchItem (Comparable[] arr, Comparable searchValue)
  {
    if (arr.length == 1 && arr[0].compareTo (searchValue) == 0)
      return true;
    else if (arr.length == 1)
      return false;
    return arr[0].compareTo (searchValue) == 0 || searchItem (Arrays.copyOfRange (arr, 1, arr.length - 1), searchValue);
  }
```

Comment: In `Arrays.copyOfRange` the second parameter is exclusive, meaning that , e.g. `Arrays.copyfOfRange(new Integer{ 1, 2 }, 1, 1).length == 0`. You're dropping the last two arguments from the array. Using print statements to print out the array should demonstrate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3rd param of `copyOfRange` is the copyTo index exclusive of the element - i.e. the element at the copyTo index is not copied. So you need arr.length there & not arr.length - 1

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(boolean[],%20int,%20int)

```
from - the initial index of the range to be copied, **inclusive**
to - the final index of the range to be copied, **exclusive**. 
     (This index may lie outside the array.)
```

So you need `searchItem (Arrays.copyOfRange (arr, 1, arr.length), searchValue)`

A much more simple recursive program is this

```
if(arr.length == 0)
    return false;

if(arr[0].compareTo(searchValue) == 0)
    return true;

return searchItem(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length), searchValue);
```

Comment: @JohnA. The way to troubleshoot this is to add the following 2 statements at the beginning of the search function System.out.println(arr.length);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); Then you would have figured out yourself what's going wrong